# How do I install drivers for a Powercolor R9 290?

Tags: drivers

I got all my parts together for this great new machine, and got it put together. It's working, but Team Fortress 2 does not run at all (maybe 2-3 fps?), and in System Info, it tells me that the system graphics are 0.4 Gallium. With this info, I'm pretty sure the system isn't using my R9 290. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 once today, but after fiddling around with the terminal, I decided to restart. That was a mistake: now the whole thing doesn't do anything. Oh well, I'm frustrated, and clueless, anyway, so might as well start over.

I'm not sure what to do. Please walk me through step by step, and assume I understand nothing.

Parts:
i5-4590 @ 3.3 GHz
Gigabyte GA-H81M-HD2
Corsair Force LS 120 GB
PowerColor Radeon R9 290

Comment: So first off, what does "whole thing doesn't do anything" mean? Can you elaborate on that? Can you also upload the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link here?

Comment: I have reinstalled, so don't worry about issues that I spoke of before, I apologize for even mentioning them. However, I am still uncertain as to how I should go about figuring out whether the system is running on the graphics card or not, and how to make it. Should system details display the name of the graphics card that is running? Because it still just says "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits)", which I assume is the integrated graphics on the processor. Thank you for your time!

Comment: System Settings -> Details -> Overview (the default tab) should tell you. There will be a "Graphics" row. Is that what you quoted above? Another method is to look into the log file I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I quoted. I followed [This](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) tutorial to the tee with the new install, and have done nothing other than attempt to install Steam through the Software Center, but that's not working. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11422783/) is `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` , as you requested.

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam`, which successfully installed Steam, so that issue is out of the way.